# MySQL JOIN irregular Tables

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL (5.7), and I am wanting to join 2 tables bases on an ID and Timestamp.

My tables look like:

Primary Table:

```
+--------+---------------------+-------------+
| UserId | Timestamp           | Information |
+--------+---------------------+-------------+
|      5 | 2015-11-29 11:15:00 |           1 |
|      5 | 2015-11-29 11:30:00 |           1 |
|      5 | 2015-11-29 11:45:00 |           1 |
|      5 | 2015-11-29 12:00:00 |           1 |
|      5 | 2015-11-29 12:16:00 |           1 |
+--------+---------------------+-------------+
```

Secondary Table:

```
+--------+---------------------+-------------+
| UserId | Timestamp           | Information |
+--------+---------------------+-------------+
|      5 | 2015-11-29 11:00:00 |           2 |
|      5 | 2015-11-29 11:30:00 |           2 |
|      5 | 2015-11-29 11:45:00 |           2 |
|      5 | 2015-11-29 12:00:00 |           2 |
|      5 | 2015-11-29 12:01:00 |           2 |
|      5 | 2015-11-29 12:02:00 |           2 |
|      5 | 2015-11-29 12:03:00 |           2 |
|      5 | 2015-11-29 12:04:00 |           2 |
|      5 | 2015-11-29 12:05:00 |           2 |
|      5 | 2015-11-29 12:06:00 |           2 |
|      5 | 2015-11-29 12:07:00 |           2 |
|      5 | 2015-11-29 12:10:00 |           2 |
|      5 | 2015-11-29 12:15:00 |           2 |
|      5 | 2015-11-29 12:16:00 |           2 |
+--------+---------------------+-------------+
```

What I want to do is return all records (from both Primary and Secondary tables). If the record does not exist in one or the other tables, it would return null.

The records in each table can come in at different time intervals.

The query that I am using is:

```
SELECT UserId, Timestamp, PrimaryInformation, SecondaryInformation
FROM (
    SELECT
        UserId,
        Timestamp
        Information AS PrimaryInformation,
        null AS SecondaryInformation
    FROM Primary
    WHERE UserId = 5 AND Timestamp BETWEEN '2015-11-29 11:00:00' AND '2015-11-29 12:20:00'

    UNION

    SELECT
        UserId,
        Timestamp
        null AS PrimaryInformation,
        Information AS SecondaryInformation
    FROM Secondary
    WHERE UserId = 5 AND Timestamp BETWEEN '2015-11-29 11:00:00' AND '2015-11-29 12:20:00'
) t
GROUP BY UserId, Timestamp, PrimaryInformation, SecondaryInformation
```

This returns:

```
+--------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------------------+
| UserId | Timestamp           | Primary Information | Secondary Information |
+--------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------------------+
|      5 | 2015-11-29 11:00:00 |                null |                     2 |
|      5 | 2015-11-29 11:15:00 |                   1 |                  null |
|      5 | 2015-11-29 11:30:00 |                   1 |                  null |
|      5 | 2015-11-29 11:30:00 |                null |                     2 |
|      5 | 2015-11-29 11:45:00 |                   1 |                  null |
|      5 | 2015-11-29 11:45:00 |                null |                     2 |
|      5 | 2015-11-29 12:00:00 |                   1 |                  null |
|      5 | 2015-11-29 12:00:00 |                null |                     2 |
|      5 | 2015-11-29 12:01:00 |                null |                     2 |
|      5 | 2015-11-29 12:02:00 |                null |                     2 |
|      5 | 2015-11-29 12:03:00 |                null |                     2 |
|      5 | 2015-11-29 12:04:00 |                null |                     2 |
|      5 | 2015-11-29 12:05:00 |                null |                     2 |
|      5 | 2015-11-29 12:06:00 |                null |                     2 |
|      5 | 2015-11-29 12:07:00 |                null |                     2 |
|      5 | 2015-11-29 12:10:00 |                null |                     2 |
|      5 | 2015-11-29 12:15:00 |                null |                     2 |
|      5 | 2015-11-29 12:16:00 |                   1 |                  null |
|      5 | 2015-11-29 12:16:00 |                null |                     2 |
+--------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------------------+
```

This returns duplicated Timestamps, rather than merging them.

The way that I need it to return would look like:

```
+--------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------------------+
| UserId | Timestamp           | PrimaryInformation  | SecondaryInformation  |
+--------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------------------+
|      5 | 2015-11-29 11:00:00 |                null |                     2 |
|      5 | 2015-11-29 11:15:00 |                   1 |                  null |
|      5 | 2015-11-29 11:30:00 |                   1 |                     2 |
|      5 | 2015-11-29 11:45:00 |                   1 |                     2 |
|      5 | 2015-11-29 12:00:00 |                   1 |                     2 |
|      5 | 2015-11-29 12:01:00 |                null |                     2 |
|      5 | 2015-11-29 12:02:00 |                null |                     2 |
|      5 | 2015-11-29 12:03:00 |                null |                     2 |
|      5 | 2015-11-29 12:04:00 |                null |                     2 |
|      5 | 2015-11-29 12:05:00 |                null |                     2 |
|      5 | 2015-11-29 12:06:00 |                null |                     2 |
|      5 | 2015-11-29 12:07:00 |                null |                     2 |
|      5 | 2015-11-29 12:10:00 |                null |                     2 |
|      5 | 2015-11-29 12:15:00 |                null |                     2 |
|      5 | 2015-11-29 12:16:00 |                   1 |                     2 |
+--------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------------------+
```

Could someone please point me in the right direction for this.

Thanks :)

Comment: I guess u need left join instead of union. Does secondary table cover all the timestamps in primary?

Comment: I have had a play around with different JOINs with no luck.

The timestamps could, but not necessarily match up between the 2 tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting them all because the rows in each query are distinct.

You could run the same query but without Primary and Secondary information and that will give you the distinct User / Timestamp.

Then LEFT join that to Primary and secondary on UserId and TimeStamp.

Something like this.....

```
SELECT UserId, Timestamp, P.PrimaryInformation, S.SecondaryInformation
FROM (
    SELECT
        UserId,
        Timestamp
    FROM Primary
    WHERE UserId = 5 AND Timestamp BETWEEN '2015-11-29 11:00:00' AND '2015-11-29 12:20:00'

    UNION

    SELECT
        UserId,
        Timestamp
    FROM Secondary
    WHERE UserId = 5 AND Timestamp BETWEEN '2015-11-29 11:00:00' AND '2015-11-29 12:20:00'
) t
LEFT OUTER JOIN Primary P ON P.UserId = t.UserId and P.Timestamp = t.TimeStamp
LEFT OUTER JOIN Secondary S ON S.UserId = t.UserId and S.Timestamp = t.TimeStamp
GROUP BY UserId, Timestamp, PrimaryInformation, SecondaryInformation
```

Also, I don't think you need the GROUP BY as you are not doing any aggregation here.  Perhaps your getting it mixed up with ORDER BY.
You could also move the WHERE and only have it once just after the JOINS but maybe you have done it like you have for a reason.

But anyhow, here's what I think it should be more like.....

```
SELECT UserId, Timestamp, P.PrimaryInformation, S.SecondaryInformation
FROM (
    SELECT
        UserId,
        Timestamp
    FROM Primary  
    UNION
    SELECT
        UserId,
        Timestamp
    FROM Secondary
) t
LEFT OUTER JOIN Primary P ON P.UserId = t.UserId and P.Timestamp = t.TimeStamp
LEFT OUTER JOIN Secondary S ON S.UserId = t.UserId and S.Timestamp = t.TimeStamp
WHERE 
  t.UserId = 5 AND t.Timestamp BETWEEN '2015-11-29 11:00:00' AND '2015-11-29 12:20:00'
ORDER BY 
  UserId, Timestamp, PrimaryInformation, SecondaryInformation
```

Comment: The second block seemed a bit slow, but the first worked perfectly. And GROUP BY wasn't needed

Comment: I'd put it in a stored procedure and call that.
Proce would take in UserId, StartDate and EndDate.

Sooner or later you'll do a typo and put in mismatched parameters otherwise.  

Glad I helped ;)